# Hide posts on Homepage and Display only in sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide posts that belong to a particular category on homepage and let it display only in sidebar.

I can successfully hide posts on homepage but I can't display it in the sidebar.

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
     if ( $query->is_home ) {
      $query->set( 'cat', '-14' );
    }
    return $query;
 }

 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' ){
```

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create shortcode and add it in sidebar this will work for you. Follow the steps as:
In your function.php add following code:

```
 function wpb_postsbycategory() {
      // the query
     $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'announcements', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); 
     // The Loop
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
         while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $string .= '<li>';
                        $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 50, 50) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
                } else { 
                         // if no featured image is found
                        $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
                }
             }
    } else {
      // no posts found
    }
     $string .= '</ul>';
     return $string;
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
}
  // Add a shortcode
  add_shortcode('categoryposts', 'wpb_postsbycategory');

 // Enable shortcodes in text widgets
 add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

 Now Add [categoryposts] shortcode in the text widget and save it.
```

This might work for you...

Answer (score 0):

create a sidebar.php with this code

```
<aside role="complementary">
    //Display your Post here
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ) ) : ?>
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</aside>
```

And then you can add the sidebar like this in your page:

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
```

To display a particular post of a category u can do it like this:

```
<aside role="complementary">
<?php
    $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'annonce',
            'tax_query' => array (
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'annonce_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'Tanzpartner gesucht', 'Tanzpartnerin gesucht' ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        .....
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And this displays the post in the sidebar  ... how?

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I only want to display posts that belongs to a particular category. Can't see where to slot in the ID of the category. Hope you get my point?

Comment: Updated post ^^ hope that answers ur question

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be using this plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/ ). It queries the posts based on different characteristics (category included). It works through the use of shortcodes.